# Flex - how to enable trace messages from Flex SDK?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I've configured Flash Debug player to log trace messages from my Flex application to the flashlog.txt file. I can see trace() messages from my own code, thats ok.

However, would also like to see also trace messages from Fle SDK. I use Flex SDK ver. 4.1, and, for example, I would like to have trace message

trace("app initialize app");

which is placed in function initialize() in mx/core/Application.as file in the SDK.

What I need to do? Should I recompile SDK somehow or is there a compiler switch to enable this? I'm a beginner in Flex, so I'm sorry if this question sounds silly.

Thank you,
Michal

Comment: Do you use Flex SDK in console mode?

Comment: Do you want to ask that how to compile your file in flex? can you tell me how you compile your file now?

Comment: I use Flash Builder 4.0, compiling Flex app in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a huge difference between the source files you modified and the SDK your Flash Player actually uses. The one your player uses already is compiled (it appears as an swc somewhere on your disk). To see the trace statements you put in the source files, you should recompile the Flex SDK, which I do not recommend to you : it would be a huge loss of time, and quite complicated for a beginner.

What I recommend is to extend the Flex class where you put a trace statement, and integrate it to your application. This way, while recompiling your app, you'll include your changes and see you trace statements.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Actually I didn't wan to add new trace() calls to the SDK source codes, I wanted just to log traces that are already there, by the authors of the SDK. But your answer was very helpful anyway, it pointed me to the idea that I can extend mx:Application class and add my own trace() calls, which can be logged easily. Thank you